# Indexing empty numpy array with empty list

Tags: python, numpy

I am having problems when indexing empty numpy arrays with empty lists.

It works fine for one-dimension arrays:

```
>>> a = ones(0)
>>> a
array([], dtype=float64)
>>> ind = []
>>> a[ind]
array([], dtype=float64)
```

If I create an empty array with 3 columns, I get an error:

```
>>> b = ones((0, 3))
>>> b
array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
>>> b[ind]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index
```

I am trying to extract no rows from an array with 0 rows and 3 columns. I would expect to get an empty 0x3 array, the same as I get when the array is not empty:

```
>>> c = ones((2, 3))
>>> c
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> c[ind]
array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
```

Is there a reason why it doesn't work for empty 2-dimensional arrays? Is there any way to make this work in python?

Comment: Works fine with me ... no error occuring ... have `numpy` version `1.8.2`

Comment: Cant reproduce it neither with numpy 1.8.1

Comment: I am using numpy `1.6.1`. Thanks, I will update to newer version

Comment: It probably relates to [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1769)